# Find the max number of points contained in a rectangle with the given area

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given an array of Points b[0..n-1], each having .x and .y coordinates. n may be large.

Devise an efficient algorithm for problem:Given an area, find the max number of points contained in a rectangle with the given area.

I want it to be done on time complexity O(n^2 *k) where k is max points in rectangle or better.

Comment: absolutely not... it is my requirement for a project.

Comment: @Algor7 You should give some context on what the project is about, it may tell a lot about optimization (for example if the set of points can be described by a function).

Comment: Is it about rectangle with horisontal and vertical sides or it can be arbitrary rotated?

Comment: Sorry to mention that rectangle must be axis-aligned

Answer (score 0):

If you have vertices of a triangle, this is very simple. You can solve cross product for every point in array `b`.

You can calculate `Cross1 = [AO, AB], Cross2 = [BO, BC], Cross3 = [CO, CA]`.

For example `Cross1 = AO.x * AB.y - AO.y * AB.x`.

Each variable `Cross1, Cross2, Cross3` must be the same signum.

You check this for each point and you count points into rectangle. Then you have `kN = O(N)`.

[image: rectangle]

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The problem is not about checking which points are inside a given shape, but about choosing and positioning a shape to optimise the number of points in it. (If a question is a bit vague, it's best to ask for clarification first, before you put effort into answering it.)

Comment: Sorry to mention that rectangle must be axis-aligned

Comment: Sorry you are misunderstanding the problem statement. Rectangle is not given only area is given and we have to find all possible rectangles of same area and then find which rectangle has maximum points contained within it. We are not interested in the rectangle but interested in maximum point count.